# Unable to decode int field from JSON

Tags: json, go, decode

My goal is to read JSON file. Although the following program reads the file fine, the `id` field value is incorrect. `id` field value is `0` for all the objects read.

Example JSON file contents:

```
{
  "users" : [
    {
      "id" : "1",
      "name" : "Matt Hayden"
    },
    {
      "id" : "2",
      "name" : "David Warner"
    },
  ]
 }
```

JSON file reader program in Golang

```
 type Schema struct {
    Id int `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`

 }

 func reader() {
    fileName := "./input.json"

    jsonFile, fileErr := os.Open(fileName)
    if fileErr != nil {
        _ = errors.Errorf("failed to open file %s : %v", fileName, fileErr)
    }
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    bytesRead, readErr := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
    if readErr != nil {
        _ = errors.Errorf("failed to read json file %s : %v", fileName, readErr)
    }

    var sch Schema
    unMarshalErr := json.Unmarshal(bytesRead, &sch)
    if unMarshalErr != nil {
        _ = errors.Errorf("failed to unmarshal JSON bytes : %v", unMarshalErr)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", sch)
 }
```

Actual output:

```
 {Users:[{Id:0 Name:Matt Hayden} {Id:0 Name:David Warner}]}
```

Expected output:

```
 {Users:[{Id:1 Name:Matt Hayden} {Id:2 Name:David Warner}]}
```

Comment: I have no clue of go, but numbers in JSON don't have a string literal - that might be your error.

Comment: That's it. Also it's Matt Hayden ;)

Comment: also make sure the key names are consistent: `id != Id`

Comment: @JoshSharkey not necessary - it's normal in Go to have different cases for JSON and the structs they marshal to. The annotations next to the field tell Go how to marshal/unmarshal the JSON.

Comment: Except JSON _very much is_ case sensitive so if Go automagically resolves `Id` as `id` that's _really bad_ and one would expect that specifically for JSON parsing that kind of resolution does not kick in because it'd be pretty ridiculous if it did. `a = { id: 3, Id: 4 }` is both valid JS, and leads to valid JSON `{"id": 4, "Id": 5}`.

Comment: Having said that: your JSON shows `users` but your JSON schema does not. So you probably want to add that.

Comment: `go doc encoding/json.Number` does the trick for the JSON part.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an extra type in your JSON struct tag. Take a look at the Marshal documentation [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/VqZu9SrnpW4

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Response struct {
    Users []User `json:"users"`
}

type User struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id,string"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    r := &Response{}

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{
  "users" : [
    {
      "id" : "1",
      "name" : "Matt Hayden"
    },
    {
      "id" : "2",
      "name" : "David Warner"
    }
  ]
 }`), &r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v \n", r)
    fmt.Printf("Type of ID is %s \n", reflect.TypeOf(r.Users[0].ID)) // int
}
```